# How to change a string to a URL and import it as an image?

Tags: javascript, string, image, url

I am thinking of something like this:

```js
let img_1 = "./img/image.png";
let player = 1;
document.getElementById("player_img").src = "img_" + player;
```

then it can display `./img/image.png` on the webpage

but the code above does not work, what is the right code?

Comment: Do you want the `src` to be `"img_1"`? Or are you expecting something else?

Comment: Dont Put The Dot At The Starting Of The String in `img_1` and it will work just fine. (If You Want To Put The Image Using Relative Path)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably the best approach is use an array.

Like this

```
let img_ = ["./img/image.png","./img/image.png","./img/image.png"];
let player = 1;
document.getElementById("player_img").src = img_[player - 1];
```

Comment: maybe `img_[player - 1]`?